# Numpy not producing desired sample variance value

Tags: python, numpy, variance

I have a list for which I like to calculate **sample variance**. When I use `numpy.var` I get a different result from the function I defined.

Can someone please help me understand what I am missing?

```py
my_ls = [227, 222, 218, 217, 225, 218, 216, 229, 228, 221]


def calc_mean(ls):

        sum_tmp = 0
        for i in ls:
                sum_tmp = sum_tmp + i

        return round(sum_tmp/len(ls), 2)

def calc_var(ls):

        tmp_mean = calc_mean(ls)

        tmp_sum = 0
        for i in ls:
                tmp_sum = tmp_sum + ((i - tmp_mean)**2)

        return round(tmp_sum/(len(ls)-1), 2)


calc_var(my_ls)
>>> 23.66

np.var(my_ls)
>>> 21.29
```

23.66 is my desired value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The denominator in the case of `np.var(my_ls)` by default is the total sample size (N).

You can use the [**Delta Degrees of Freedom (ddof)**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.var.html) parameter in `numpy` to show you're calculating the **sample variance** by setting `ddof = 1` for the mean degree of freedom. I.e. your denominator now becomes (N-1)

```py
np.var(my_ls,ddof=1)
>>> 23.66
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ddof` parameter of [`np.var()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.var.html#numpy-var), which stands for "degrees of freedom":

```
np.var(my_ls, ddof=1)
# 23.65555555555555
```

to get you to the desired result.

Essentially, you divide your sum of squares by `n - 1`, while `np.var()` divides by `n - ddof`, which defaults to `0`.
A discussion on these topics can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Population_variance_and_sample_variance).

Answer (score 1):

You are using the unbiased formula for the variance, i.e. you are dividing the summatory by N-1, while `np.var` seems to compute the variance normalizing by the total number of elements in the vector.

Check for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance), section "Sample variance".

Answer (score 1):

your function `calc_var(ls)` doesn't implement variance [formula](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.var.html):

> The variance is the average of the squared deviations from the mean,
>   i.e., `var = mean(abs(x - x.mean())**2)`.

you can use:

```
def calc_var(ls):

        tmp_mean = calc_mean(ls)

        means = []
        for i in ls:
                means.append((i - tmp_mean)**2)

        var = calc_mean(means)
        return round(var, 2)

print(calc_var(my_ls))
print(np.var(my_ls))
```

output:

```
21.29
21.29
```

Comment: thank you! I was trying to calculate sample variance, while `numpy.var` actually gave population variance

Comment: There is no need to use the `abs` function, because every number to the 2nd power will give a nonnegative result.

Comment: @kederrac, the abs function has no role here: `(x-y)**2` and `(abs(x-y))**2` provide the same result, since (mathematically speaking) `(x-y)**2` = `(y-x)**2`